# vue: escape and render HTML string?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to render some HTML string in template, but I want them to be string, I don't want to render "rich text"

I started with:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{'something <like /> this'}}</div>
</template>
```

but vue will render the code above into follwing:
`<like />` will be rendered as html tag

```html
<div>{{'something <like></like> this'}}</div>
```

but what I want is this:

```html
<div>something &lt;like/&gt; this</div>
```

I know I can put the text inside `data`

```html
<template>
<div>{{text}}</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'something <like /> this'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

but this would become tedious, and how can I do it directly inside template

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to replace the characters `<` and `>` as you've pointed out, but you'll also need to use the `v-html` directive since the tags in the string literal break the mustache binding.

In your script:

```
methods: {
  htmlToText(html) {
    return html.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
  },
}
```

In your template:

```
<div v-html="htmlToText('something <like/> this')"></div>
```

Doing `<div>{{ htmlToText('something <like/> this') }}</div>` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pre-process your string first like this

```
text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

Then you can use it in the template