# Why vhtml not rendering nested << properly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an app that uses dynamic binding where <> is a dynamic way of getting value from API. But when I am trying to render it in vhtml, its not even showing the parent element. I want it like Name: `<<Name>>`. How this can be achieved? . I have attached the example code.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      htmlText: '<p> Name : <<Name>> </p>'
    }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<span v-html="htmlText"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of [Link's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1325887/linh-nguyen) and [Xlm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/885922/xlm) answers on [vue: escape and render HTML string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926348/vue-escape-and-render-html-string)

Parse the incoming string with a regex that replaces < with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;`

**Please note** that this could be just a **workaround**. If you want a **cleaner solution**, you should do this in the **API**.

In your case,

```js
 const app = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data() {
      return {
        htmlText: "<p> Name : <<Name>> </p>",
      };
   },
   methods: {
      htmlToText(html) {
          return html.replace(/<</g, "&lt;&lt;").replace(/>>/g, "&gt;&gt;");
      },
   },
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <span v-html="htmlToText(htmlText)"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```